# "jar cvf ui.jar -C bin ." doesn't seem to work for me

Tags: eclipse, plugins, jar, hsqldb

While setting up the HSQLDB plugin for eclipse, I've run into issues creating a ui.jar file (via the console command) in my hsqldb.ui directory.  When running the command

```
jar cvf ui.jar -C bin .
```

I constantly get a message saying "jar" is not recognized as an internal command.  The JRE and JDK files are set up properly, at least I assume (as I've been running eclipse for 2 months now).  So, I'm at a loss for what to do.

Any bump in the right direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jar executable should be located in the bin directory under your java sdk installation.

You will need to add that bin directory to your system environment PATH variable if you want your shell or console window to find it.